# Keep UIDatePicker from Growing too Wide

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a view hierarchy on iOS arranged like this:

```
UIViewController
  - UIView
    - UIButton
    - UIButton
    - UIScrollView
      - UIStackView
        - UILabel
        - UIDatePicker
        - UILabel
        - UIDatePicker
```

The scroll view is pinned to 20 from leading and trailing space on the superview, 0 from the bottom of one of the buttons, and 0 to the bottom layout guide.

The stack view has 0 leading, trailing, top, and bottom space to the superview (the scroll view).

I like how this looks in vertical orientation:
[image: Vertical screenshot]

But in horizontal orientation, I think the long lines extending beyond the main content of the `UIDatePicker` are kinda ugly:
[image: Horizontal screenshot]

I've tried many permutations of constraints (max width + center X on the `UIDatePicker`s, increasing various content hugging priorities, no width constraints on the `UIScrollView` and center X on it), but all have resulted in ambiguous layouts or conflicting constraints. How can I do what I'm aiming for here?

EDIT: With the constraints as suggested below (ScrollView pinned to container, StackView pinned with 0 Trailing, Leading, Bottom, and Top space to the ScrollView, and a width equal constraint on the date pickers) the StackView refuses to expand its width and stays pinned to the left of its parent.

[image: StackView stuck to the side]
[image: StackView stuck to the side, with view rectangles]

This happens even though there are leading and trailing constraints set to 0 on the StackView.

Comment: Also, having now tested this a bit on a physical device, having the `UIDatePicker` extending to the edge of the screen makes it quite difficult to scroll.

Comment: You have added constant Leading and Trailing space that will keep it on same dimensions all the time. (In Portrait or Landscape mode).

Comment: Indeed. The issue is I don't know what constraints to replace the leading/trailing constraints with. Everything I've tried so far has resulted in ambiguous or conflicting layouts.

Comment: How do you want to dispay both pickers in Landscape mode?

Comment: I'm the same orientation and position, just not as wide. If I limit their width, though, other constraints break.

Comment: Yes, Do one thing. Instead of making Leading and Trailing constant, make width constant.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Alignment` of `UIStackView` to **Center**.

[image]

Add a width constraint to DatePicker = 315

Now the `stackview` will keep the `DatePicker` to `Center` with width 315 in both potraite and landscape

[image]

Comment: Could you expand this a bit with what constraints should be placed on the other objects? Particularly the scroll view and the stack view.

Comment: Just add width constraint to both DatePickers.  ie width = 315. Stackview is just pinned from four side. No width constraint to stackview

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. Please see my update above.

Comment: @ScottColby : Change the Alignment of UIStackView to Center. Its available in property inspector

Comment: I have made that change. The DatePickers, etc. are properly centered in the StackView. The StackView itself is not centered in the ScrollView.